# Prägnante deutsche Übersetzung von "Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish."

Tags: translation, idiom

In seiner bekannten [Rede bei der Absolventenfeier in Stanford 2005 prägte Steve Jobs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF8uR6Z6KLc&t=830) den Ausdruck

> Stay hungry. Stay foolish.

Ich verstehe die Bedeutung der Worte, suche aber eine prägnante Übersetzung, die dem Original nahe kommt und auf Deutsch gut klingt.

**Update:**

Habe in der Jobs-Biographie gelesen, dass das Zitat ursprünglich aus dem Magazin "The Whole Earth Magazine" (1974) stammt. Siehe auch meine [Antwort auf English-SE zur Frage *Stay hungry. Stay foolish*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44538/what-does-the-phrase-stay-hungry-stay-foolish-mean/46602#46602).

Comment: Die erste Frage, vor jedem Übersetzungsversuch, wäre herauszufinden, was Steve Jobs (oder besser: Stewart Brand im Whole Earth Catalog) mit diesen Worten gemeint haben könnte. Im Kontext der Gegenkultur der 60er und 70er Jahre, verstehe ich dieses Zitat so: "Bleibe hungrig nach Leben, und habe weiterhin den Mut, dich aus gewohnten Bahnen herauszubewegen." Eine deutsche Übersetzung müsste eine für unsere Sprache und unseren Kulturkreis geeignete Formulierung finden, die diesen Kern der Hippie-Philosophie ausdrückt.

Comment: Die letzte Seite des Catalogs kann man sich übrigens hier auf Seite 324 ansehen: http://www.wholeearth.com/issue-electronic-edition.php?iss=1180

Answer (score 12):

> *"Bleib unzufrieden. Bleib wagemutig."*

Das "Hungern nach Erfolg" ist im Deutschen m.E. zu negativ besetzt, daher bin ich auf "unzufrieden" ausgewichen. Bei "foolish" habe ich zwischen "unvernünftig" und "wagemutig" geschwankt, aber letzteres trifft m.E. die Intention besser.

**EDIT**: Eine ganz freie Übersetzung, die das "Hungrige" vielleicht besser aufgreift und gerade das Nicht-Hungern negativ darstellt:

> "Werdet nicht satt (und träge). Seid verrückt genug, mit etablierten
>   Konventionen zu brechen!"

Ich muss allerdings sagen, dass mir das als Übersetzer eine viel zu freie, interpretative Übertragung ins Deutsche wäre.

Comment: Finde ich gut übersetzt, eine derartige Phrase kann in der Übersetzung nie genauso gut klingen und noch exakt dieselbe Bedeutung haben. Ich stimme zu, dass hungrig in diesem Kontext extrem negativ ist. Man könnte sich aber auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass Jobs bewußt negativ angehauchte Worte verwendet hat, um den rebellischen Charakter zu betonen, insofern ist diese Übersetzung vielleicht eine Spur zu glatt gebürstet.

Comment: "Unzufrieden" ist für mich sogar noch um Einiges negativer als "hungrig"... Wie wäre es mit "Gebt euch nicht zufrieden"? Zwar ein Fragment, aber als Übertragung für "hungry", das hier auch nur aus dem Kontext korrekt erschließbar ist, ginge es vielleicht... "Wagemutig" finde ich auch gut.

Comment: @Phira: Wenn der Erfolgshunger selbst negativ besetzt ist in Deutschland, wieso soll dann die Übersetzung den Leser schonen, die Differenz kaschieren? Soll Jobs Deutsch rüberkommen?

Comment: @user unknown: Ich denke, dass eine Phrase, die im Englischen positiv besetzt ist, in der wörtlichen Übersetzung jedoch einen negativen Ton erhält, so übersetzt werden sollte, dass der gewünschte Ton getroffen wird, statt sich an die Wortwörtlichkeit zu klammern. Du sagst ja selber einschränkend, dass der negative Eindruck am Deutschen liegt. Ich verstehe aber, wenn Übersetzer lieber die wortgetreue als die sinngemäße Übersetzung bevorzugen. Verfremdungseffekte gibt es in beiden Fällen.

Comment: Die Einschränkung irgendwelcher Adjektive auf die 2 Schubladen 'positiv' und 'negativ', die ich selbst oben vorgenommen habe, ist aber viel zu primitiv, und wird der Sache nicht gerecht. Das eine ist die Eigenschaft, und das andere die Bewertung. Ich finde es wird zu viel, zu kleingeistig und holzschnittartig bewertet - wenn der Leser das macht, ist es sein Bier. Wenn Jobs 'hungrig' gesagt hat, hat er 'hungrig' gesagt. Wem dass schon zu negativ ist, der soll sich die Ohren abscheiden und die Augen blenden lassen, dass er es nicht zufällig lesen muss.

Answer (score 10):

Nachdem es bereits eine brennende philosophische Diskussion darüber gibt, was Steve Jobs mit ["Stay hungry. Stay Foolish."](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2005/june15/jobs-061505.html) wohl gemeint haben könnte, verfälscht jede Übersetzung, die bereits eine Interpretation des mutmaßlich Gemeinten beinhaltet, das Original.

Ich würde also eine wörtliche Übersetzung bevorzugen:

> Bleibt immer hungrig und erhaltet euch euren Leichtsinn!

Comment: Gibt es wirklich eine Diskussion darüber? Ich meine, die Beschreibung des karriereorientierten Neulings als "hungrig" schon häufiger in angloamerikanischer Literatur gelesen zu haben. Mir war nicht bewußt, dass dieses Bild erstmalig von Jobs verwendet wurde.

Comment: Woher kommt das "immer"?

Comment: @fzwo: *to stay* kann durchaus mit *immer bleiben* übersetzt werden, ohne dass sich die Bedeutung dadurch ändert, zumal da *to stay* stärker ist als *bleiben*.

Comment: I really like "erhaltet euch euren Leichtsinn"... although it is not nearly as short as the original it is the best possible option in German

Comment: Bei dieser Übersetzung (und ähnlichen Vorschlägen aus anderen Antworten) würde ich mich ehrlich gesagt fragen, wieso man denn nichts essen soll, bzw. ob hier nebenbei für eine Diät geworben wird. Meiner Meinung nach ist die Verwendung der Wortfamilie um "Hunger" im übertragenen Sinn im Deutschen bei Weitem nicht so verbreitet wie im Englischen; im Deutschen sollte eine solche Verwendung viel eher explizit qualifiziert werden ("Hunger nach Neuem", "Hunger nach Fortschritt" etc.), um verständlich zu sein, als dies im Englischen notwendig sein mag.

Answer (score 9):

> Stay hungry. Stay foolish.

würde ich primär mit

> Bleibt hungrig, bleibt naiv!

übersetzen. `Naiv` gilt meist als schlechte Eigenschaft, hat einen Beigeschmack von unaufgeklärt/dümmlich, den `foolish` aber für mich auch hat. Man könnte es gemessener ausdrücken durch ein feierliches:

> Bewahrt Eure Naivität!

aber das würde eben einerseits einen so nicht vorhandenen, feierlichen Ton einbringen; insbesondere, wenn man jetzt auch `Bewahrt Euren Hunger` benutzte, um beide Phrasen gleich anklingen zu lassen.

`Naivität bewahren` klingt schon mal freundlicher. Die Kindheit, die Blümchen, ...

Comment: Naivität halte ich in diesem Zusammenhang für unpassend. Seid nonkonformistisch, agiert abseits gewohnter Denkschemata, das ist eher im Sinne des von Jobs gegebenen Ratschlags, wie eine Kritik der Etablierten augenzwinkernd vorwegnehmend, die solche Vorgehensweisen als "foolish" betrachten würden. Nichts davon finde ich im Begriff "Naivität" wieder. Der beschreibt eher einen Zustand des Nichtbegreifens.

Comment: Naivität wird oft Kindern zugeschrieben, denen man auch eher einen Vorurteilsfreien Zugang attestiert. Wer nicht die Traditionen der etablierten Alten kennt, der findet vielleicht eine unverbrauchte Lösung?

Comment: Diese Übersetzungen passen am meisten.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich finde es gewagt, diese beiden Aspekte (die in der Tat beide Kindern zugeschrieben werden) miteinander in Zusammenhang zu bringen. Ich tue mich jedenfalls sehr schwer damit, mir eine Situation vorzustellen, wo jemand (Kind oder nicht) zugleich auf Grundlage eines vorurteilsfreien Zugangs handelt (und somit, wie du sagst, eine unverbrauchte Lösung findet) *und* sich naiv verhält (was für mich irgendwie vermittelt, dass man die Bruchstücke der Traditionen, die man kennt, blindlings akzeptiert und somit gerade *keine* unverbrauchte Lösung findet).

Answer (score 4):

> Bleibt wissbegierig. Bleibt neugierig

oder etwas freier

> Bewahrt das kindliche in euch/die kindliche Neugierde

So würden es angehende Wissenschaftler/Erfinder an der Uni imho verstehen. Angesehen hab ich mir die Rede aber nicht.

Answer (score 4):

**Bleibt hungrig, bleibt verrückt!**

Bleibt hungrig nach dem Leben - nach Eurem eigenen, einmaligen Leben!
Und bleibt verrückt - kümmert Euch nicht um kleinliche Einwände, glaubt an Eure Mission, verliert keine Zeit.

Answer (score 3):

> Ein Wissensdurst macht niemals satt; so siecht in der Wirr.

Steve Jobs' Aussage umreißt ein einfaches "Ohne Fleiß kein Preis" zusammen mit einem "Hochmut kommt vor dem Fall". Er spricht davon, dass man als selbstverliebter Alleswisser nie erfahren sein könnte.

Zugegeben, meine deutsche Version davon ist etwas alt.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be:

> Bleibt begierig, bleibt offen.

`begierig` differs a bit from the other suggested translations, but I think it is simply wrong to translate it as `hungrig`. It is true that terms like `abenteuerhungrig` do exists, in which `hungrig` is used to express desire, however the short form suggested here does sound more than strange to me. Ultimately, he refers to insisting on a burning desire, an apetite for challenge, one such that claims you and takes hold of you, and thus I ended up with `gierig`, and in this case, the slightly milder `begierig`. Equally to `hungry`, `begierig` has the objective negative meaning of strong want for something, yet `begierig` does also have a certain amiable and well meaning tone to it. (Er trank seinen Becher begierig aus. - meaning not he was greedily drinking, but he enjoyed it.)

`bleibt offen` translates the meaning more than the implication of the word. Obviously `bleibt offen` does not reflect the notions of true foolishness, that his saying does not explicitly exclude it. However, it is my point of view that at the core, the foolishness he refers to, is a constructive and creative one, not a genuine one.

Answer (score 2):

"Bewahre Deinen Wissensdurst und Deine kindliche Neugier."

Comment: Ich denke, es sollte "Bewahrt euren Wissensdurst und eure kindliche Neugier" sein, da sich die Rede von Jobs an eine Menge richtet.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist alt und es gibt schon viele Antworten, aber hier das entsprechende Zitat aus der offiziellen Jobs-Biografie auf deutsch - ISBN 978-3-641-07462-3.

> Jobs wurde ein Fan dieses Katalogs [Whole Earth Catalog, siehe Anmerkung von OP]. Vor allem die letzte Ausgabe, die 1971 erschien, als er noch zur Highschool ging, faszinierte ihn. Er brachte sie mit zum College und dann zur All One Farm. »Auf der Rückseite der letzten Ausgabe befand sich ein Foto von einer Landstraße im Morgengrauen, eine, auf der man vielleicht trampen würde, wenn man das Abenteuer suchte. Darunter stand: **›Bleibe hungrig. Bleibe verrückt.‹**«

Answer (score 0):

am Treffendsten finde ich: Bleibt hungrig, bleibt töricht!

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Wäre es möglich/sinnvoll, diese kurze Antwort noch etwas auszuführen? Z.B. warum diese wörtliche Übersetzung den 2005 genutzten Ausdruck aus 1974 hier in deutscher Sprache genau dasselbe meint wie im Englischen? (und wie es dort vermutlich gemeint war?)

Answer (score 0):

Ich finde viele der hier ausgeführten Antworten treffend und eventuell macht genau das ein gutes Zitat so wirksam. Das man es auf viele Arten treffend interpretieren kann.
Als ich das Zitat das erste Mal hörte, war für mich auch die Kernaussage:
"Bleibt hungrig, bleibt töricht!"
Diese Übersetzung trifft einerseits eine Lebenseinstellung von Steve Jobs zu lebenslangem lernen und andererseits das törichte Herangehen an Probleme, in denen man sich manchmal doch einfach aber viel zu häufig, durch ihre Komplexität verliert.
Eine andere Interpretation von dem Wort foolish wäre mit dem deutschen Wort "tollkühn" zu übersetzen. Was für mich die Bedeutung des Wagemutes intensiviert. Immer wissenshungrig zu bleiben und sich auch auf Risiken einzulassen, um Grenzen zu sprengen. Dies unterstreicht auch seine Rolle als Visionär.

Answer (score -3):

Stay hungry - stay foolish
Der Sinn dahinter: "Sei realistisch - versuch das Unmögliche!" Aus meiner Sicht trifft das genau den Kern der Aussage von Jobs.

Comment: Wie passt das "Sei realistisch" zu "Stay hungry"?